# Install sqlite3 for php8.3 on Ubuntu server working with nginx

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu

I want to enable sqlite for a website running with php 8.3. This website should use sqlite, but when I try to install it (like in php 8.2) `sudo apt install php8.3-sqlite3` it doesn't work. How to install sqlite in php 8.3 ?

I think sqlite has no big changes between php 8.2, is it possible to copy from php 8.2?

---

I try `sudo apt install php8.3-sqlite3`. But it return

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.3-sqlite3
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.3-sqlite3'
```

I looked on some obscure forums. They say to compile my own sqLite to use it, but it's too obscure for me without a real tutorial

Comment: First check: Did you perform update thru `sudo apt update` first (before `sudo apt install php8.3-sqlite3` )?

Comment: A simple Search will get you to https://linux-packages.com/ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/package/php83-sqlite3

Comment: You might also get better results asking UBUNTU based questions on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @KenLee yes same result

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's exactly what I did and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: See my answer below (well - tested)

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu server - assuming that you are using the Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (Long-term Support)

Make sure you have added the necessary repository (e.g.  ppa:ondrej/php repository for php), using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

and also make sure you have updated / upgraded apt, and installed the necessary ca-certificates, etc. using

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade

sudo apt-get install ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common
```

After that, you should be able to install php8.3-sqlite3 thru the following

```
sudo apt install php8.3-sqlite3
```

Of course I assume that your have already added PHP support to Nginx, such as adding the following to
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
location ~ .php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
}
```

So, the following will be the necessary commands to install (you may notice that I have added the line `sudo apt-get purge 'php*'` to remove previously installed php versions)

```
sudo -s

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt update && apt upgrade

sudo apt-get install ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common

sudo apt install nginx 

sudo apt-get purge 'php*'

sudo apt install php8.3 php8.3-fpm php8.3-mysql php8.3-imap php8.3-ldap php8.3-xml php8.3-curl php8.3-mbstring php8.3-zip

sudo systemctl enable php8.3-fpm --now

sudo systemctl restart nginx

sudo apt install php8.3-sqlite3

sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

See the screen dump below which clearly shows that it works: (will **NOT** show something like `Unable to locate package php8.3-sqlite3`)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used a backup to revert to php 8.2, I don't know if it works for me but I think so